# Clang Standard C Library

Tags: c, embedded, clang, llvm

I'm working with an embedded environment that has no operating system or filesystem. I'm looking for a minimal C-library with at least stdio, stdlib and math implementations - though more would be better.

The library will have to be ported as there is definitely no implementation out there for this architecture. The compiler for this architecture uses LLVM, so the library must be able to build with clang.

Can anyone suggest a good candidate? Some I have looked at already:

1. newlib http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/ (doesn't build with clang AFAIK)
2. uClibc http://www.uclibc.org/ (doesn't build with clang)
3. pdclibc http://pdclib.e43.eu/ (no math support)

Comment: Questions that asks where to find a library or other off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might want to see if Android's Bionic will work for you (I have no idea how easily it'll work with clang): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git

Comment: I believe it's at least possible to build *against* Bionic with clang in recent versions of the Android tools, not 100% sure if you can build it, but probably.  That may be a more full-featured library than desired - an Android device starts to be as much like a desktop of a few years ago as a traditional embedded target.  Also it seems intended to be supported by and wrap syscalls of a Linux kernel, which would require some adaptation.

Comment: I suggest that you pick one of newlib or uClibc and fix whatever is preventing then from compiling.  clang is a compiler not a different language; the reasons for build failure are probably minor, and perhaps the only GCC specific part are the makefiles and not the code at all.

Comment: It seems like this is a legitimate question. He is looking for a specific set of requirements: bare-metal and clang compatible. Something like I'm working on. http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=2389